# Installed files location for clickonce application

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have implement a windows application in VS -2010 , I have used local database database1.sdf.
I have publish this Application and generate exe file and install application in my computer, my application works fine , I can insert data to database , now i need database1.sdf but i cant find where this database locate at the time of installation , how can i find folders where all files related to application  stored(normally when we install any programme in computer it generate folder under Programme Files , but i cant find such folder for my application)?
Thanks

Comment: You can try opening Task Manager, going to the Details view, and opening the file location of the process? It should be in the local application directory. But where in the local application directory? Again, open Task Manager -> Details -> Select your process -> Open file location. You can google this "installed files location for clickonce application", and the first result goes to a StackOverflow post in March 2010 with the answered question in much more detail.

Comment: @Jason i have already tried this  , but at that location i cant find database file...